# Coffeescript closures and arrays of random numbers

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, functional-programming, closures

Running the following coffeescript consistently results in an array of all false.
My question is "Why?"

```
class A
    probability: 0.5
    gen: (f) -> f() for x in [0...10]
    init: -> alert @gen -> Math.random()<@probability
    constructor: -> @init()

new A
```

This is in contrast to the following almost identical script,
which generally returns a mix of true and false,

```
class B
    gen: (f) -> f() for x in [0...10]
    init: -> alert @gen -> Math.random()<0.5
    constructor: -> @init()

new B
```

as does the following

```
probability = 0.5
gen = (f) -> f() for x in [0...10]
init = -> alert gen -> Math.random()<probability

init()
```

and the following

```
gen = (f) -> f() for x in [0...10]
init = -> alert gen -> Math.random()<0.5

init()
```

Why does the first script have a different behavior from the others, especially from the second?
It is, of course, useful to keep the probability parameter as a variable.

Am I missing something about closures?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the ["fat arrow"](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) to execute the callback in the correct context:

```
alert @gen => Math.random()<@probability
```

Otherwise `this` doesn't refer to the correct object inside the callback, and `@probability` gets resolved to the wrong value.

---

Alternatively you could change `gen` so that the callback is always executed in the context of the instance (i.e. as instance method):

```
f.call(this) for x in [0...10]
```